# How should we use [references]?

Tags: discussion, tags

As it stands now, [references](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) is being used for two different things, as is reflected by the usage guidance, I wrote. It is being used for:

- questions looking for specific references,
- and questions about references in books.

This shows that this tag is not unambiguous. So, **How should we use it and/or change it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Questions looking for specific references” is not a useful tag. It characterizes answers, not questions.

I'm perfectly aware that several sites have such a tag, including one that I moderate (where it's called `reference-request`). But the tag serves no useful function. It vaguely indicates the nature of the expected answers, but it is not a subject of expertise, and it is not useful in a search (if I'm looking for a reference for X, I won't limit my search to questions with the tag `reference-request`, because many answers on questions that weren't specifically requesting references do include references).

So forget about looking for a name for a tag meaning “questions looking for specific references”. For the meaning “references in books”, I like [muru's suggestion](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/470) [allusions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allusions).

Answer (score 4):

We could split it up into [sources](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources) (or maybe [citation](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation)?) and [allusions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allusions), which are unambiguous about which meaning of "references" they use. Of the four posts currently tagged [references](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references), I think three would fall under [allusions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allusions):

- [Are there any debated authorship references in Thursday Next series?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/126/)
- [What reference is Shakespeare making in Act 2 Scene 2 of Macbeth?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/102/)
- [Was Isidora's fate in Melmoth the Wanderer directly inspired by Faust?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) seems to be more suited to [inspiration](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration), but it could use [allusions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allusions).

None would be suitable yet for [sources](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources), since I don't see what [references](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) has to do with [What section of literary theory does "pure" analysis fall into?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/) (unless OP is asking for [sources](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources) which define sections of "literary theory").

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking.